# Python program not handling long integers for Diffie-Hellman implementation

Tags: python, largenumber, diffie-hellman

Im creating a Python program that implements the Diffie-Hellman protocol for Computer Security...

The program is supposed to take a single input, p, from the user which is the size of a prime number in bits.

I've coded all of it, except *when I input a bitsize over 50, it will not give me an output.* Im assuming its because of the extremely large numbers it is working with.

values g, a, and b are supposed to be parameter values in the group {1, 2, ..., p-1}, in which case, its supposed to be a random integer from this group.

**Problem Block of Code**

```
A = (g ** a) % p
B = (g ** b) % p
k1 = (B ** a) % p
k2 = (A ** b) % p
```

**The Whole Program**

```
import random
import math
import sympy

p_bits = input("Enter number of bits of prime number: ")
p_bits = int(p_bits)

p_bitsmax = ((2 ** p_bits) - 1)
p_bitsmin = (2 ** (p_bits - 1))

p = sympy.randprime(p_bitsmin, p_bitsmax)

g = random.randint(1, p-1)
a = random.randint(1, p-1)
b = random.randint(1, p-1)

A = (g ** a) % p
B = (g ** b) % p
k1 = (B ** a) % p
k2 = (A ** b) % p

print("The value of p selected:", p)
print("The value of g selected:", g)
print("The value of a selected by Alice:", a)
print("The value of b selected by Bob:", b)
print("The value of A sent to Bob by Alice:", A)
print("The value of B sent to Alice by Bob:", B)
print("The value of shared key computed by Alice:", k1)
print("The value of shared key computed by Bob:", k2)
print("")

if k1 == k2:
    print("The shared keys match.")
else:
    print("The shared keys don't match. Something went wrong.")
```

EDIT:

After testing the code in Jupyter Notebook, I see it has no problems assigning random values to g, a, and b, but rather it can't compute A, B, and shared keys with bit sizes over 50.

Comment: First thing that pop out: the `random` module is not  cryptographically safe. See the red warning in the docs!

Comment: Are you able to determine where the hang occurs? For example, if you only have the code up until `p = sympy.randprime(p_bitsmin, p_bitsmax)`, can you get a result for `p`?

Comment: I believe the problem lies where I assigned random.randint(1, p-1) to g, a, and b. When I change the range to (1, 50), I get a result back. However in this case, after I input a bitsize over 50, no results come back.

Comment: Python has a modular exponentiation function, so you can write `pow(g, a, p)` instead of `(g ** a) % p`.  This is *vastly* more efficient, as no intermediate value greater than `p` needs to be kept.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!